# Iterating all possibilities of a simple instruction set

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinatorics

say I have a very simple model of an instruction set:

```
opcode 0, arg1[0-1]
ocode 1, arg1[0-2], arg2[0-1]
```

So what I'm looking for is a way to build up infinity complex programs with it.

The first program is:

```
0,0

next is,
0,1

then
0,0
1,0,0

then
0,0
1,1,0

etc
```

Such that, given an arbitrary instruction set defined by:

```
class Instruction
{
   public int opcode;
   public int[] argLimits; //the maximum value of each argument, and number of arguments
}
Instruction[] allInstructions;
```

Can generate the next program given the previous program.
eg: `ExecutableInstruction[] GetNextProgram(ExecutableInstruction[] previous, Instruction[] instructionSet);`

The argument's value limit will always be [0-n]
The arguments are all required - if an opcode takes 3 arguments, they are all required.

I know how to do this sort of thing when the number of arguments is fixed, but when each opcode can have N arguments where each argument for each opcode can be of value 0-n, I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enumerate your instructions along with all possible argument values, e.g.:

```
A: 0,0
B: 0,1
C: 1,0,0
D: 1,0,1
E: 1,0,2
F: 1,1,0
G: 1,1,1
H: 1,1,2
I: 1,2,0
J: 1,2,1
K: 1,2,2
```

Now any program is an arbitrary word over the `A-K` alphabet. I hope you know how to continue.